# nested linked list print issue

Tags: c, nested

When I running this code and call " List() "function it prints only the last added by user . I want to print from beginning to the end.I hope you will help me about my list function.It prints only the last one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct seat {
    int k_no;
    int k_name;
    struct seat *next_k, *previous_k;
} *first_k, *temp_k, *last_k;


struct sefer {
    char name[20];
    int no;
    struct sefer *next, *previous;
    struct seat *bus;
} *first, *last, *temp;

void list();
void seat_link(int val);
void sefer_search();

int main() {
    int val;
    printf ("how many names do you want to type ->"); 
    scanf ("%d", &val);

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < val; i++) {    
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = (sefer *)malloc(sizeof(struct sefer));
            fflush(stdin);
            printf(" %d. name->", i + 1);
            scanf("%s", &first->name);

            printf(" %d. capacity ->", i + 1);   
            scanf("%d", &first->no);

            first->next = NULL; //2 inci düğüm daha oluşmadığı için null
            first->previous = NULL;
            last = first; //şimdilik sadece ilk düğüm olduğu için aynı zamanda son oluo

            last->bus = NULL;

            for (j = 0; j < first->no; j++) {

                //KOLTUKLAR OLUŞTURULCAK

                if (last->bus == NULL) {

                    first_k = (seat *)malloc(sizeof(struct seat));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    first_k->k_no = j;
                    first_k->k_name = 1;

                    first_k->next_k = NULL; 
                    first_k->previous_k = NULL;
                    last_k = first_k; 
                    last->bus = first_k;                  
                } else {
                    temp_k = (seat *)malloc(sizeof(struct seat ));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    temp_k->k_no = j;
                    temp_k->k_name = 0;

                    last_k->next_k = temp_k;
                    temp_k->previous_k = last_k;
                    last_k = temp_k;
                    last_k->last_k = NULL;            
                }       
            }
        } else if (last == first) {
            printf("\n");
            last = (sefer *)malloc(sizeof(struct sefer));
            fflush(stdin);
            printf(" %d. name ->", i + 1);
            scanf("%s", &last->name);

            printf(" %d. capacitiy ->", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &last->no);

            first->next = last;
            last>next = NULL;
            last->previous = first;

            last->bus = NULL;

            for (j = 0; j < last->no; j++) {
                //KOLTUKLAR OLUŞTURULCAK
                if (last->bus == NULL) {
                    first_k = (seat *)malloc(sizeof(struct seat ));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    first_k->k_no = j;
                    first_k->k_name = 2;

                    first_k->last_k = NULL; 
                    first_k->previous_k = NULL;
                    last_k = first_k; 
                    last->bus = first_k;
                } else {     
                    temp_k = (seat *)malloc(sizeof(struct seat));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    temp_k->k_no = j;
                    temp_k->k_name = 0;

                    last_k->next_k = temp_k;
                    temp_k->previous_k = last_k;
                    last_k = temp_k;
                    last_k->last_k = NULL;
                }       
            }
        } else { // kayıt eklenmişse diğer düğümler oluşturulcak      
            printf ("\n");
            temp = (sefer *) malloc(sizeof(struct sefer));
            fflush(stdin);
            printf(" %d. name", i + 1);
            scanf("%s", &temp->name);

            printf(" %d. capacity->", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &temp->no);

            last->next = temp;
            temp->previous = last;
            last = temp;
            last->next = NULL;

            last->bus = NULL;

            for (j = 0; j < temp->no; j++) {
                //KOLTUKLAR OLUŞTURULCAK
                if (last->bus == NULL) {
                    first_k = (seat*)malloc(sizeof(struct seat));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    first_k->k_no = j;
                    first_k->k_name = 3;

                    first_k->last_k = NULL; 
                    first_k->previous_k = NULL;
                    last_k = first_k; 
                    last->bus = first_k;
                } else {
                    temp_k = (seat *)malloc(sizeof(struct seat));
                    fflush(stdin);

                    temp_k->k_no = j;
                    temp_k->k_name = 0;

                    last_k->next_k = temp_k;
                    temp_k->previous_k = last_k;
                    last_k = temp_k;
                    last_k->next_k = NULL;
                }       
            }
        }
    } 

    list();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;        
}


 void sefer_search() { //bağda arama yapar
    int searching;

    printf("\n\t\t Aranacak Sefer Numarasını Giriniz:");
    scanf("%d", &searching);

    temp = first;

    while (1) { 
        if (temp->no == searching) {
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    } 
}


void seat_link(int val) {
    int j;              
}
```

my problem is here actually :

```
void list() {
    temp = first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("\t%s --%d \n", temp->name, temp->no);
        temp = temp->next;
    }        

    printf ("\n");

    last->bus = first_k;
    while (last->bus != NULL) {               
        printf("\t%d --%d \n", last->bus->k_name, last->otobus->k_no);
        last->bus = last->bus->next_k;       
    }  
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Your program won't even compile: `deg`, `sefer` and `koltuk` are all *undeclared identifiers* and there are other errors `xxx` is not a member of `yyy`.

Comment: He claims that his code compiles and works so I'm taking him at his word there. Perhaps he should elaborate further if they really are necessary in addressing this issue, but from what I see, it's a pointer problem.

Comment: Yes  , I think the same way you do. It is probably pointer problem but I haven't figured it out what should I do for fix that pointer problem(s) yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code.  Firstly, it won't compile for various reasons.  For instance, you sometimes use a `struct koltuk` without ever defining it.  "koltuk" means "seat" in Turkish, so I'm going to assume you meant `struct seat` in all those cases.  Secondly, `deg` is undefined; I assume you meant `val`.

There were a few other problems like that which I was able to fix by making plausible guesses.  But that leaves the following fundamental problems:

1. You are using global variables as local variables, for instance `temp_k` and `temp`.  This makes it well-nigh impossible for a human to analyze your code and understand the control flow.
2. You have copied code all over the place.  You have three separate code blocks to allocate and initialize a `sefer` depending upon whether it's first in the global linked list, second, or later.  Use subroutines!
3. Your data model seems confused.  You have global variables `struct *first_k,*temp_k,*last_k;` which makes it seem like you have one global linked list of seats for all `sefer` structs, but the `struct seat` does not refer back in an obvious way to the `sefer` that owns it, which implies that each `sefer` has a separate, private list of `seat`s.

Taking all three problems together, I can't really see where, specifically, you are going wrong.  I took a cut at rewriting your code to eliminate these problems.  Give it a try to see if it solves your problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct seat{
    int k_no;
    int k_name;
    struct seat *next_k, *previous_k;

} seat;

typedef struct sefer {
    char name[20];
    int no;
    struct sefer *next,*previous;
    struct seat *bus;

} sefer;

void list();

sefer *sefer_search();

void link_sefer(sefer **pp_first, sefer **pp_last, sefer *p_added)
{
    p_added->next = p_added->previous = NULL;
    if (*pp_first == NULL)
    {
        *pp_first = *pp_last = p_added;
    }
    else
    {
        (*pp_last)->next = p_added;
        p_added->previous = *pp_last;
        *pp_last = p_added;
    }
}

void link_seat(seat **pp_first, seat **pp_last, seat *p_added)
{
    p_added->next_k = p_added->previous_k = NULL;
    if (*pp_first == NULL)
    {
        *pp_first = *pp_last = p_added;
    }
    else
    {
        (*pp_last)->next_k = p_added;
        p_added->previous_k = *pp_last;
        *pp_last = p_added;
    }
}

sefer *create_and_link_sefer(sefer **pp_first_sefer, sefer **pp_last_sefer, int i)
{
    sefer *new_sefer;
    seat *p_first_seat = NULL;
    seat *p_last_seat = NULL;
    int j;


    // Allocate and initialize sefer

    printf ("\n");
    new_sefer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct sefer));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf (" %d. name->",i+1);
    scanf ("%s",&new_sefer->name);

    printf (" %d. capacity->",i+1);
    scanf ("%d",&new_sefer->no);
    new_sefer->bus = NULL;

    // Link sefer

    link_sefer(pp_first_sefer, pp_last_sefer, new_sefer);

    // Allocate seats
    for(j=0;j<new_sefer->no;j++){

        //KOLTUKLAR OLUŞTURULCAK
        seat *p_seat = calloc(1, sizeof(struct seat));
        fflush(stdin);
        p_seat->k_no=j;
        p_seat->k_name = (j != 0 ? 0 : (i+1 > 3 ? 3 : i+1));  // I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHAT THIS IS SUPPOSED TO BE

        link_seat(&p_first_seat, &p_last_seat, p_seat);
    }

    new_sefer->bus = p_first_seat;

    return new_sefer;
}

void sefer_list(sefer *first, sefer *last){

    sefer *temp=first;
    while (temp !=NULL)
    {
        seat *seat;

        printf("\t%s --%d \n", temp->name,temp->no);

        for (seat = temp->bus; seat != NULL; seat = seat->next_k)
        {
            printf("\t\t%d --%d \n",seat->k_name, seat->k_no);
        }

        printf ("\n");
        temp=temp->next;
    }   
}

sefer *sefer_search(sefer *first, sefer *last){ //bağda arama yapar

    int arama;
    sefer *temp;

    printf ("\n\t\t Aranacak Sefer Numarasını Giriniz:");
    scanf ("%d",&arama);

    temp=first;

    while (temp != NULL){

        if (temp->no==arama){
            break;
        }

        temp=temp->next;
    } 

    return temp;
}

sefer *first = NULL;
sefer *last = NULL;

int main( )
{
    int val;
    int i;

    printf ("how many names do you want to type ->"); 
    scanf ("%d",&val);

    for(i=0;i<val;i++){
        create_and_link_sefer(&first, &last, i);
    }

    sefer_list(first, last);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work, but since I don't know what you are trying to do, it might not be working as you want.

Comment: Yes , I changed variables names because of maybe it understand easily in English.However I missed some words.Sorry about that.By the way the code is working.Beside all of them , can you give me your  e-mail adress , please ?

Comment: So how are commenters expected to know the difference between code that is incorrectly coded and code which is incorrectly copied?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the logic, that means that `temp` really isn't going anywhere. My guess is that when you set those pointers `*first, *last, *temp;` in the first few lines of `main`, you don't really point `first` to `NULL`, causing it to skip the first if statement. Pointers don't point to NULL by default, they point to whatever was at that memory location beforehand. In this case, garbage. Try adding `first=NULL;` prior to your first if-statement.

Comment: Thank you but ,I added first = NULL ; top of the main function.However still doesn't working I have same problem. –